# Jetpack Compose: IntrinsicMeasurements not supported loading with Accompanist CoilImage in DropdownMenu

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to build a dropdown menu with items that contain not only text, but also an image. The image should be loaded from an url. I'm using Dropdown Menu and Accompanist to load the image.
But when I try to open the Dropdown Menu, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Intrinsic measurements are not currently supported by SubcomposeLayout.

I've tried to play around with Intrinsics in my Composables like here https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts#10, but it didn't work. If I don't use CoilImage, but get a painter from resources with Image, everything works fine.

Is there a way to solve it?

```
@Composable
fun DropdownChildren(
    items: List<ChildUiModel>,
    chosenChild: ChildUiModel?,
    onChildChosen: (ChildUiModel) -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true })) {
            ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
                imageUrl = "https://oneyearwithjesus.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/shutterstock_20317516.jpg",
                text = items[selectedIndex].name?: "No name",
                chosen = false)
        }

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 500.dp)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, child ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = if (child.id == chosenChild?.id) appColors.secondary else appColors.primary),
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                        selectedIndex = index
                        onChildChosen(items[selectedIndex])
                }) {
                    ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
                        imageUrl = "https://oneyearwithjesus.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/shutterstock_20317516.jpg",
                        text = child.name,
                        chosen = child.id == chosenChild?.id)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
    imageUrl: String,
    text: String,
    chosen: Boolean
){
    Row(){
       Avatar(url = imageUrl)
        Text(text = text,
            style = AppTheme.typography.h4,
            color = if (chosen) appColors.primary else appColors.secondary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Avatar(
    url: String
){
    val contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp, 8.dp, 12.dp, 8.dp)
    CoilImage(
        data = url,
    ) { imageState ->
        when (imageState) {
            is ImageLoadState.Success -> {
                MaterialLoadingImage(
                    result = imageState,
                    contentDescription = "avatar",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(contentPadding)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .size(48.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    fadeInEnabled = true,
                    fadeInDurationMs = 600,
                )
            }
            is ImageLoadState.Error -> CoilImage(
                data = "https://www.padtinc.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/plc-errors.jpg",
                contentDescription = "error",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(contentPadding)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .size(48.dp)
            )
            ImageLoadState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
            ImageLoadState.Empty -> {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned on the [bug](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/224), this has already been fixed in v0.8.0 of Accompanist. You need to use the new `rememberCoilPainter()` though, and not the deprecated `CoilImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

CoilImage is now Deprecated,

use this

```
Image(
    painter = rememberCoilPainter("https://picsum.photos/300/300"),
    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.image_content_desc),
    previewPlaceholder = R.drawable.placeholder,
)
```